# Библиотека SDPO

Tags: lazarus

Почему не ставится SDPO? требует какой-то synaser

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что в SDPO работа с портами реализована на базе [synaser](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php). Именно поэтому она и требуется. Библиотека свободно распространяется и может быть скачана (ссылку я привёл) и использована.

Comment: Спасибо большое